# LINQ / Objects howto remove items and add them to another list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using Linq with objects and have a question.

Actual workload is processed in a background job.

The actual workload should not be put to further tasks. It is more important, that the method which processes the actual workitems does it quite fast and gives a result, therefore the complete workload is put to chunks of workitems.

At a time, I only process the first n objects of the list, therefore I take n objects and then remove them from the complete list of workitems.

```
Roughly:

int amount = 100;
List<WorkItem> actualWorkload = null;

lock(lockWorkload){ // complete Workload is filled in other thread
    if (actualWorkload.Count > amount)
    {
        actualWorkload.AddRange(completeWorkload.Take(amount));
    }
    else
    {
        actualWorkload.AddRange(completeWorkload);
    }
    completeWorkload.RemoveAll(x => actualWorkload.Contains(x));
}
//do something with workitems Process(actualWorkload);
```

My question is: can 'Take' and 'Remove' be somehow combined, so that there is only one step to take items and directly remove this items from a list? I search fro something liek the 'Take' of a BlockingCollection which removes an item while it is returned.

Comment: If using .net 4.0 and above, check out ConcurrentQueue<T>, it handles the locking for you, and you call Dequeue on it without need to take and remove from different lists.

Comment: Before a BlockingCollection was used. The problem was that for the method which is called it needs a amound of items and not only one. With the take/dequeue and the 'Add' is was slower (the add to a list seemed to be a problem, AddRange performed better without reinventing AddRange)

Answer (score 0):

Even if there would be an operation that allows that, in the background it would still need to remove and add them.

But maybe you don't need two lists? Maybe you could have only one list with all items, and each item has a status that you set to a different value or something. But of course, I don't know your exact case so this may not be feasible.

Comment: The two lists are used to have locking only in one place. (For optimzation not only one object is taken and processed). If locking is done while processing a lot of time can be used (depending on the methods filling the list. This way it was a lot faster. I know that it still needs to remove and add them. I was only thinking that time could maybe reduced if the complete list only needs to be accessed once (RemoveAll/Contains needs to do much comparisions). I don't know if 'Take(100)' and 'RemoveRange(0,100)' always would access the same elements (the list cannot be changed in meantime)

Answer (score 0):

"Take and remove" sounds to me a lot like "Dequeue", so perhaps you could just use a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) or a [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)?

However, the enumerator does NOT remove items from the queue, so you would have to call [Dequeue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.dequeue.aspx) repeatedly yourself.

Comment: 'Dequeue' would only access one item. 'Add' n-times to a list takes a lot more time then 'AddRange'. That is the reason why in this case BlockingCollection is not used. (Performance bottleneck was found in the complete method, now it locks okay, but as it is known that the method can be a bottleneck the question is wether it can be further optimized - the thing was that it was getting faster with 'Take' and 'AddRange' then with a for-loop, the duration in the lock can directly affect the other threads accessing items from the list)

Comment: If you're finding that much overhead, it seems to imply that your work units are too small. Perhaps you could consider encapsulating several work units into a single item (as some kind of collection) and enqueuing those instead. Then dequeuing a set of work items would only involved dequeuing a single item.

Comment: The producers work independend and give a lot of small informations. Some are redundant (which is not a problem if independend sensors measure the same values), some are noise. The data is then cleaned in bulks to reduce some noise (not completly, but the bulk size is enough for a preprocess step, the data cleanup is then done at a later time with real processing (which is to slow without pre cleanup - also to much data which would not needed to be used gets stored)). So this is a first rough cleanup.